Android Studio Jellyfish: Emulator doesn't start
Each time I have to restart my PC (Win10) to run Android emulator again. When I press an emulator without PC restart, it freezes at Starting up and nothing happens. Also running virtual device freezes on shutting down. Any thoughts? Thanks.

IDE:
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  idea.plugin.protoeditor (233.14808.14)


Which acceleration technology/hypervisor do you use  WHPX or AEHD? See https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-vm
